# lib for custom password input with type text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, passwords, libs

In our site we have two input field with type password - for login and for password. Because of this, now autofill are working incorrect. Browsers dont remember login and paste password to login field. We need the login field to have the same form as the password (with dots instead of symbols), but at the same time field type must be text that the autofill works currect. I'm thinking of writing a custom field in which the text will be replaced with dots. But maybe there is already some ready-made solution in the form of a library, where can I get such a field? Tell me please.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, it helped me: https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-security

I did not install the library itself, but I took the necessary fonts and connected them.